# Is there a way I can run Selenium Webdriver with Ruby bindings test suite and once it is done running, carry on writing tests further in irb?

Tags: ruby, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am running test suite with Selenium Webdriver and Ruby Bindings.
Everytime I have to write script for new functionality I have to run entire code manually in IRB to reach particular level from where I can carry on further with trial and error method for CSS Selector method.

Whole objective for this would be to avoid manually running the script as it is time consuming.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: @Arran Not sure what you mean by that? I am not using IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using irb, you don't need to run entire code. Instead of executing entire code before the point which you want to check with selector methods, perform those steps manually and then proceed with trial and error for the element you want to check. Of course, you'll have to create browser instance in irb like following:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
# here perform manual steps to reach to point where you want to perform trial and error and then try with trial and error
driver.find_element(:css, "css_selector")
```

EDIT:

If you want to do above through script, please go [here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/11-build-an-interactive-prompt)

Comment: Thats what I meant to skip, is there any way where we can stop the script running and switch to irb from that instance for trial and error?

Comment: If I understood you, you want to run script say `test.rb` and stop it somewhere and then switch to irb and do trial and error. Answer is this is not possible. But there is workaround for this. Please refer to http://elementalselenium.com/tips/11-build-an-interactive-prompt